# How to map CMD+Alt alone to the command?

Tags: key-bindings, terminal, macos

I am trying to map <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> to start searching in vim (`/`). The only question is: how would I do this? I know to map <kbd>Alt</kbd> in vimscript is by typing `<A>` but I do not know how to do <kbd>Cmd</kbd>.

I also want to press the keys at the same time (not one after the other)

Comment: Are you using MacVim? Or Vim from a terminal?

Comment: I am using terminal.

Comment: @MartinTournoij Do you imply by your comment that this is possible in MacVim?

Comment: I don't know @Hotschke, I probably added it because it *may* be possible, and keymapings work quite different technically on the terminal vs. a GUI, so solutions could differ.

Comment: @MartinTournoij. I see. Thanks for your quick response. I did not find anything in the help page dedicated to MacVim: [`:h macvim`](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/blob/master/runtime/doc/gui_mac.txt). I guess [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) could help here by mapping `Cmd`+`Alt` if pressed alone to `/`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible. In the terminal, no key code is generated for modifiers alone.

Gvim also has no support for this, partly because there is no valid way to represent the key using the map commands.

Comment: Oh well, Looks like I will map ll to / then. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [`keycodes`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#keycodes), towards the end of the table is:

```
<M-...>         alt-key or meta-key             meta alt <M-
<A-...>         same as <M-...>                 <A-
<D-...>         command-key (Macintosh only)    <D-
```

Combinations would look like `<D-M-x>`.

Though I don't think a combination of modifiers alone can be mapped (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>,<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

#### Map `Cmd`+`Opt` if pressed alone to `/` with [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/)

1. Install Karabiner Elements
2. Install following custom complex modification:

```json
{
  "title": "Change Cmd_L and Option_L to Slash (/)",
  "rules": [
    {
      "description": "Change Command_L + Option_L (Alt) to slash (/) if pressed at the same time and without any other key.",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "left_option",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "left_command"
              ],
              "optional": [
                "any"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to_if_alone": [
            {
              "key_code": "slash"
            }
          ],
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "left_option",
                "modifiers": [
                    "left_command"
                 ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "left_command",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "left_option"
              ],
              "optional": [
                "any"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to_if_alone": [
            {
              "key_code": "slash"
            }
          ],
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "left_command",
              "modifiers": [
                    "left_option"
                 ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

i) Copy json file to the correct location:

```
$ cp cmd-opt-alone-to-slash.json ~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications
```

ii) Import rules from Karabiner-Elements Preferences.
    `Karabiner-Elements Preferences > Complex Modifications > Rules > Add rule`