# Map left command key to left control key in terminal only?

Tags: key-bindings, command-line, terminal, macos

I've asked [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/416076/map-left-command-key-to-left-control-key-in-terminal-only) over on AskDifferent without any luck.

I'm using neovim to edit code and am needing to create a mapping to bind  to `<cmd-w>` to `<C-w>`.

How would I go about this on macOS?

In fact I am unable to bind anything to `<cmd-...>` as my terminal seems to be intercepting the instruction for an OS-level key binding.

The only way I've thought to get around this is to use Karabiner-Elements; yet, I am not competent enough to write an **application-specific key binding** just for **neovim**.

- macOS: **Catalina 10.15.7**
- Terminal: **Alacritty@latest**
- neovim: **v0.4.4**
- karabiner-elements-**@latest**

Comment: I think you should give more details on what you actually want to do with your mapping (because that might be [a XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You can't map only a modifier key in vim/neovim so you can't only map `ctrl` -> `Cmd` but maybe you want to map a specific command? You could write `nnoremap <C-a> <M-a` this way when you press `ctrl+a` neovim with interpret it as `cmd+a`, `M` being the key code for `Cmd` on Mac [`:h keycodes`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#keycodes)

Comment: @statox the only functionality I require with the command key would be binding it to `<C-w>` in order to provide window navigation support to my thumb. Which, is currently missing.

Comment: You want only the command key? I don't think modifier keys can be used alone. https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2380/how-to-map-cmdalt-alone-to-the-command?rq=1

Comment: @BLayer how about `<cmd-w> <C-w>`?

Comment: `<D-w>` doesn't work?

Comment: @BLayer the problem I'm having is cmd-w closes the window on macOS so the instruction is captured by the OS, not the terminal and therefore not neovim.

Comment: Well, that's intercepted by the OS before it gets to (neo)vim, I'm sure, so you'll have to solve that problem at a different level. In Windows I'd use AutoHotKey....have anything like that for Mac?

Comment: @BLayer I'm trying to do that with Karabiner, obviously disabling <cmd-w> would work but I would only want to disable it on the terminal application, not the rest of the machine. E.g the "application-specific key binding" that karabiner provides; which I don't know how to supply.

Comment: AHK would definitely allow that. Unfortunately, I'm Win and Linux guy...know little about Macs. Sorry. Welcome to Vi&Vim SE, anyways. :)

Comment: @BLayer all good, thank you. I'll have to solve it by reading the karabiner docs... was hoping someone with sore pinkies had an easy plug-and-play mapping. The whole thing is in JSON so not too bad; I'll post the answer here when I figure it out. Adn thanks! Don't know how I survived without vim before.

Comment: Re: sore pinkies, I make caps lock a control key